# How could I ask to Google Cloud Platform team to develop a new extension tools (Cloud Tools For VSCode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to ask Google to develop a new extension for VSCode (Cloud Tools for VSCode) to deploy apps to Google Cloud Platform, but I don't know WHERE to do it. It's like a feature request, such as Cloud Tools For Eclipse, or Cloud Tools for Visual Studio, or Cloud Tools for Intellij. If anyone knows, please help. Thank you.

**Note**: Currently there is a VSCode extension called *Cloud Code* but is not the same as *Cloud Tools for VSCode*, that's why I'm trying to ask for it.

Comment: You mean it's not related to this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud has a website for posting bugs and creating feature requests.

[Report Issues and Request Features with Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Scroll down to "Create Tools for Visual Studio issue".

Before creating a feature request, review the existing requests.